# Automated Incremental Indexing in Solr

Tags: search, solr

I'm working implementing Solr in an environment where we want Solr to reindex files in certain directories whenever they are changed (or added). At the moment, all I am aware of is a full reindex, which is undesirable for us.
Does anyone know of a feature that provides this functionality?

Comment: How are you indexing the files now? There are multiple tools that can monitor a directory and run a script/command/etc. if any of the files change

Comment: Right now, I'm indexing the files using a bin/post over the relevant directories. Could you point me to some of those tools?

Comment: Depends on your operating system, but a few chosen ones: `inotifywait` and `iwatch` for Linux, `FolderMonitor` for Windows (external), `Folder Actions` for OS X (built-in)

Comment: I used inotifywait (Linux) and it's working exactly as desired. Thanks so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Under Linux you can use `inotifywait` to watch a directory for changes (files added/modified/deleted). You can then use that event to trigger `bin/post` to send any updated files (and if you need, remove files that have been removed).